# How to start my php project in Linux mint

Tags: php, xampp, linux-mint

Hi i am new in mint Linux and i would like to ask on how to start my php project in Linux mint.I have installed netbeans and Xampp. It's quite different from windows.  i can't get **htdocs** folder?. I tried the following

```
1)Start IDE File > Open Project
2)Set name and location.(in windows Xampp\htdocs\projectname)
```

But mint Linux how i get a path like **/home/user/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1**. I can't get **htdocs** folder. But using localhost i can't run my project.I don't know whether it's the actual way or not.Please help me.

Comment: open file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and see the path of DocumentRoot
In that path place your project folder

Comment: @Naincy there is no apache2 folder inside etc

Comment: Please see this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Why would one want to use something like `xampp` on a Linux distribution based system? It already has all required packages only three clicks away in the software management. Using `xampp` means you send out all the advantages of the software management down the drain. Great.

Comment: @Naincy -thanks a lot...comment it as answer

Comment: @Shanukk Great! it worked for you. For other users adding its as my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is bit different from windows. You will not get any **htdocs** folder in Linux.

Please see this link and follow the steps. It will help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: here my root is DocumentRoot /var/www/html .so if i want create a sample project then where i can create a folder?inside www?

Comment: inside html folder

Comment: can access it with localhost/folder_name/file.php

Comment: @nanicy open IDE folder path is still /home/shanu/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1

Comment: And can't create a folder inside html.i am sorry @Naincy for disturbing you..Actually i dont know anything about this.that's why.k

Comment: you need to give permission to html folder... Open terminal cd /var/www 
and then type ll and enter and see permission for html folder and share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136211/discussion-between-naincy-and-shanu-k-k).

Answer (score 0):

since you installed xampp, your htdocs is here:
opt>lampp>htdocs. Once there you can create a folder for your project.
for example:
opt>lampp>htdocs>florist

Then to visit the site: http://localhost/florist/yourpagename.html

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, I struggled with it though

1. Navigate to var/www/html
2. Write click on it and select open as admin

Then copy the project folder to it.
Head to the browser and localhost/projectfolder